# Strange behaviour with the sed command

Tags: linux, macos, bash, sed

There's something weird when I write that:

```
echo "VAL LES LE VAL LE VAL" | sed -E -e 's/ LES? / /g'
```

I get:

```
VAL LE VAL VAL
```

instead of:

```
VAL VAL VAL
```

The word LE after the LES one is kept, but the last LE word is well removed.

I use the sed command on Mac OS X 10.8 which dates of May 10, 2005

Does anyone know the reason of this result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) does [not recursively match output patterns](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-7). That is, the input line is read, and when a pattern is matched, the modified output is generated, and the *rest* of the input line is scanned. The "s" command will **not scan the newly created output**. Thus, after you replace the first `LES` with , the newly created space will not be scanned, and the next `LE` will not be matched since there is no leading space.

Alternative solution:

```
echo "VAL LES LE VAL LE VAL" | sed -E -e 's/ *LES?//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "VAL LES LE VAL LE VAL" | sed -E -e 's/ LES? / /g'
```

Here `<space>LES<space>` matched and got replaced by `<space>`. so the next char to start with will be `LE<space>` which doesnt match the sed expr `<space>LES?<space>` and hence was unmodified.